# On the j-function $j\big(\frac{1+\sqrt{-31}}{2}\big)$ and special cubics

Tags: radicals, modular-forms, cubics

Given the [j-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#The_q-expansion_and_moonshine),

$$j(\tau) = {1 \over q} + 744 + 196884 q + 21493760 q^2 + \dots$$

It seems that for $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{-d}}{2}$ and $d=12n+7$, then it has the form,

$$j(\tau) = 12^3(1-x^2)^3\tag1$$

where $x$ is an algebraic number of degree equal to the *class number* $h(-d)$. For example, if $d=31$, then $x$ is a root of,

$$8x^3 - 24x^2 - 90x - 81 =0\tag2$$

It is easy to solve for the real root of  $(2)$ using Cardano's formula. However, as I saw in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Special_values), it can also be expressed in the rather aesthetic form,

$$x = 1+\tfrac{\sqrt{19}}{2}\left(\left(\tfrac{13-\sqrt{93}}{13+\sqrt{93}}\right)^{1/2}\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{31}+\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{31}-\sqrt{27}}\right)^{1/3}+\left(\tfrac{13+\sqrt{93}}{13-\sqrt{93}}\right)^{1/2}\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{31}-\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{31}+\sqrt{27}}\right)^{1/3}\right)\tag3$$

For $d = 139$, we have,

$$x^3 - 141x^2 + 351x - 243 = 0\tag4$$

***Question:*** How do we express the real root of $(4)$ in a similar form to $(3)$? If it is not possible, what are the special conditions on the coefficients of a cubic so that it is expressible as such?

Comment: dunno. One thing this formalism is used for is to fill in the polynomial in Theorem 9.2 on page 180 of Cox. Here, given odd prime with $(-31|p)= 1, $ we can write $p = u^2 + 31v^2$ if and only if $z^3 + z + 1$ has a root $\pmod p,$ in fact it will be three distinct roots. Or, from page 88, ignoring the Legendre symbol, when $(z^3-10z)^2 + 31 (z^2-1)$ has a root $\pmod p$

Comment: @WillJagy:I'm trying to figure out the answer to my own question. I'm almost there, but there are still some gaps.

Comment: Cool! How the hell did you find this?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: The expression for $x$ is not mine. I just saw it in the link provided.

Comment: @WillJagy: Does Cox give conditions for prime $p = u^2+dv^2$ when $d = 31,\,331,\,547$? What do these three $d$ have in common? (See answer below for context.)

Comment: Tito, Cox would not, but if the class numbers are fairly small I can tell you from other places.

Comment: @WillJagy: Feel free to do so. I tried the OEIS, but got swamped by unneeded results.

Comment: 31 I told you what I know already. I can also give you $x^2 + xy + 83 y^2$ of discriminant $-331$ and  $x^2 + xy + 137 y^2$ of discriminant $-547.$ Note that $x^2 + 31 y^2$   and $x^2 + xy + 8 y^2$ represent the same ***odd*** numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tinkering, I managed to answer partially my question and it turns out it involves *Pell equations*.

**A.** For $d = 31$. Given the Cardano solution to the cubic,

$$8x^3-24x^2-90x-81=0\tag1$$

$$x = 1+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{187+9\sqrt{93}}{2}\Big)^{1/3}+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{187-9\sqrt{93}}{2}\Big)^{1/3}\tag{1a}$$

it seems that whoever posted the aesthetic version in the j-function [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Special_values)  essentially factored the expression within the cube root as,

$$\alpha = \frac{187+9\sqrt{93}}{2} = \beta^3\, U$$

hence a product of a cube and $U$ as a *fundamental unit*. Of the $12$ (out of $16$) *fundamental discriminants* with [class number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) $h(-d) = 3$, and with form $12n+7$, there were only *three* such that the fundamental unit $p+q\sqrt{d}$ had small $p,q$, namely $d=31,\,331,\,547$.

Thus, $(1a)$ can then be alternatively expressed as,

$$x = 1+\tfrac{1}{4}\big(13-\sqrt{93}\big)\,U_1^{1/3}+\tfrac{1}{4}\big(13+\sqrt{93}\big)\,U_1^{-1/3}$$

where,

$$U_1 = \frac{\sqrt{31}+\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{31}-\sqrt{27}}=\frac{29+3\sqrt{93}}{2} $$

with $29^2-93\cdot3^2=4$ and it will take only a little tweaking to bring $x$ to the form in the post, as with the two below.

**B.** For $d = 331$.

$$x^3 - 3957 x^2 - 5481 x - 11907 = 0\tag2$$

$$x = 1319+2\big(5773-182\sqrt{993}\big)\,U_2^{1/3}+2\big(5773+182\sqrt{993}\big)\,U_2^{-1/3}$$

where,

$$U_2 = \frac{\sqrt{1324}+\sqrt{1323}}{\sqrt{1324}-\sqrt{1323}}=2647+84\sqrt{993}$$

Note that fundamental solution of the Pell equation $2647^2-993\cdot 84^2=1$.

**C.** For $d = 547$.

$$x^3 - 60081 x^2 - 152361 x - 100359=0\tag3$$

$$x = 20027+2\big(103420-2541\sqrt{1641}\big)\,U_3^{1/3}+2\big(103420+2541\sqrt{1641}\big)\,U_3^{-1/3}$$

where,

$$U_3 = \frac{\sqrt{2188}+\sqrt{2187}}{\sqrt{2188}-\sqrt{2188}}=4375+108\sqrt{1641}$$

and $4375^2-1641\cdot 108^2=1.$

Of course, the remaining question is why $\alpha$ can be factored as $\alpha=\beta^3\, U$ with $U$ as a fundamental unit.

Answer (score 1):

make an answer so you can see. From your own answer, it appears you want $x^2 + xy + 83 y^2$ and $x^2 + xy + 137 y^2$ rather than $x^2 + 331 y^2$ and $x^2 + 547 y^2.$ So, see

[image]

If you really wanted the latter forms, those are class number $9$ and will take longer.